# Solving $2x - \sin 2x = \pi/2$ for $0 < x < \pi/2$

Tags: trigonometry

What is $x$ in closed form if $2x-\sin2x=\pi/2$, $x$ in the first quadrant?

Comment: Yes. But it seems from other posters' answers, there is no known one due to $cosy=y$.

Comment: This question seems a duplicate of
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46934/what-is-the-solution-of-cosx-x

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the solution of $\cos(x)=x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46934/what-is-the-solution-of-cosx-x)

Answer (score 8):

The solution is given by $$\displaystyle  x = \pi/4 + D/2$$

where $\displaystyle D$ is the root of $\cos y = y$

The root of $\displaystyle \cos y = y$ is nowadays known as the [Dottie Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html) and apparently has no known "closed form" solution. If you consider this number to be part of your constants, then the above can be considered a closed form solution.

---

For a proof:

If $\displaystyle y = \sin(2x)$

then we have that

$\displaystyle 2x  = \pi/2 + y$

$\displaystyle y = \sin 2x = \sin (\pi/2 + y) = \cos y$.

The root of $$\displaystyle y = \cos y$$ is $\displaystyle y = 0.739085\dots$

Notice that $\displaystyle \pi/2 > x \gt \pi/4$ (as $\displaystyle f(x) = 2x - \sin 2x$ is increasing in $\displaystyle [0,\pi/2]$), so if $\displaystyle x = \pi/4 + z$ then

$\displaystyle \sin(2x) = \sin(\pi/2 + 2z) = \cos 2z = 0.739085\dots$

And thus $\displaystyle z = \dfrac{0.739085\dots}{2}$.

Thus $$\displaystyle x \sim \pi/4 + \dfrac{0.739085}{2} \sim 1.154940730005\dots$$

See Also: [A003957](http://oeis.org/A003957).

Answer (score 3):

An analytical form of x can be obtained solving Kepler equation:

$$M= E-\epsilon \sin(E)$$

with eccentricity=1 and mean anomaly = $\pi/2$ by means of Kapteyn series:

$$2x = \frac{\pi}{2}+\sum_{n=1} \frac{2J_n(n)}{n} \sin(\pi n/2)$$

where $J_n()$ are the Bessel functions. Simplifying:

$$2x = \frac{\pi}{2}+\sum_{n=0} \left( \frac{2J_{4n+3}(4n+1)}{4n+1} - \frac{2J_{4n+3}(4n+3)}{4n+3}\right)$$

$$x = \frac{\pi}{4}+\sum_{n=0}  \left( \frac{J_{4n+1}(4n+1)}{4n+1} - \frac{J_{4n+3}(4n+3)}{4n+3}\right)$$

Such series can be numerically evaluated, but it converges slowly and n=10000 terms are required to obtain:

$$x = 1.154940317134$$

with

$$2x-\sin(2x)-\pi/2=-1.38017659479e-006$$

In order to improve the convergence, we can employ an acceleration series technique as Levin's acceleration. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration)

With only 10 (ten!) terms we obtain:

$$x=1.1549406884223$$

A simple c++ code, based on gsl library is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "gsl_sf.h"
#include "gsl_sum.h"
using namespace std;

#include <cmath>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double PIH = atan(1.)*2;
    cout<<setprecision(13);
    double E=PIH;

    cout<<"raw series"<<endl;
    //raw series
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 1e4; i +=2 )
    {
        double term = 2*gsl_sf_bessel_Jn( 2*i+1, 2*i+1 )/(2*i+1);
        double term2 = 2*gsl_sf_bessel_Jn( 2*i+3, 2*i+3 )/(2*i+3);

        E += (term-term2);
    }
    cout<< E/2<<endl;

    cout<< "error: "<<E-sin(E)-PIH<<endl;

    //levin 
    cout<<"levin accelerated series"<<endl;
    const int N = 10;
    double t[N];
    double sum_accel=0, err;

    gsl_sum_levin_u_workspace* w =
        gsl_sum_levin_u_alloc( N );

    t[0] = PIH;
    for( int i = 1 ; i < N; i++ )
    {
        double term = 2*gsl_sf_bessel_Jn( 4*i-3, 4*i-3 )/(4*i-3);
        double term2 = 2*gsl_sf_bessel_Jn( 4*i-1, 4*i-1 )/(4*i-1);

        t[i] = term-term2;
    }

    gsl_sum_levin_u_accel( t, N, w, &sum_accel, &err );

    E=sum_accel/2;

    cout<<sum_accel/2<<endl;

    cout<<"error: "<<sum_accel-sin(sum_accel)-PIH<<endl;

}
```

Comment: By the way, the formula $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2J_n(n)}{n} \sin(\pi n/2)$$ works for Dottier number.

Comment: terms for n=2,4,6,.. can be deleted (sin=0).
Therefore we could rewrite the sum as:

2$\sum_{n=0}  \left( \frac{J_n(4n+1)}{4n+1} - \frac{J_n(4n+3)}{4n+3}\right)$

Is it right?

Comment: Why the index of the Bessel functions is not equal to the argument in your expression?

Comment: I AGREE WITH YOU! TYPO!

Comment: I fixed the math. As you can see the code was consistent with the correct formula... I will fix the math also at the Dottie thread

Comment: @Anixx How does one derive the Bessel Series? Thanks.

Comment: @TymaGaidash sorry, not my area of competence...

Comment: @TymaGaidash no, sorry... I have absolutely no idea. If anything, I am currently interested in divergent integrals (classes of equivalence, multiplication, regularization) and things related to umbral calculus. Given you have so much impressive mathematical talent, I actually would be interested to know your opinions on some of these things.

Comment: @TymaGaidash particularly, there are interesting formulas that connect trigonometric and inverse trigonometric functions in closed form!

Comment: @TymaGaidash you may find some interesting formulas here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_umbra

Comment: @Anixx Thanks for the information. It seems like umbral calculus has some ties with this post. I know little about umbra, so what is bernoulli umbra and how does it connect to the inverse digamma function in the article?

Comment: @TymaGaidash do you have a e-mail? Basically, umbral calculus is a atudy of kind of an object whose consecutive powers are some well-known sequence, such as Bernoulli numbers. This alone gives a lot of "magical" formulas. Digamma funtion, Bernoulli numbers, Bernoulli polynomials are just cases of Hurwitz Zeta function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134413/discussion-between-tyma-gaidash-and-anixx).

Comment: @TymaGaidash hi, maybe there was a misunderstanding, but I came up with the solution based on Bessel's functions, So I don't understand why to ask the user Anixx , who just noticed a typographical error of mine...
This is a way in which the Bessel functions can be introduced, that is the solution of the Kepler problem, constructed by means of a Fourier integral then converted into Kapteyn series expansion. Maybe I have some old articles that might be interesting for you.

Comment: @TymaGaidash So far I have found a chapter on an old book by Tricomi in Italian "Le funzioni", I will scan it and post it on my facebook page.
Unfortunately for several years I have not enjoyed myself with these matters and in this moment I have not found anything better (I have several pdfs, somewhere...).
As I find material on this subject I will inform you

Comment: @TymaGaidash just posted three pages of "Le Funzioni" by F.Tricomi, where the link between Bessel function and Kepler problem is explained.

https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=2096081833890508&id=100004661355326

Comment: @TymaGaidash, yes, the solution is expressed (or should I say that it is forced in the form of ) as a Fourier series, and the Fourier coefficients of the series lead to the Bessel functions.

Comment: @giorgiomugnaini How is an inverse found from a fourier series?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Bessel hypothesized that the solution could be expressed as a Fourier series, then he found the coefficients (which are the Bessel functions), as explained by Tricomi (unfortunately in Italian). Or maybe I didn't understand the question ...

Answer (score 2):

Repeating the same thing as the other answers, but with a moderately more elegant one:

Let $y = 2x - \frac{\pi}{2}$, then substituting:

$y = sin(y+\frac{\pi}{2})$

$y = cos(y)$

$y = D$

then

$x = \frac{y+\frac{\pi}{2}}{2} = \frac{D}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

To get a graphical impression of the solution have a look here:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2+x+-+sin+(2+x)+%3D+Pi/2+for+x

Edit: That WA doesn't give a closed form is at least a hint that there might be none (very probable)

Comment: If you assume the Dottie number to be part of the "closed form" constants, then there is a closed form solution. See my answer.

Comment: @Moron: Well, I don't know if there is some "degree of closeness" but I guess this way you could define everything as "closed form" (which is often done btw, just think of Pi, e, Si(x), Li(x) asf...

Comment: Not sure what you mean. All I am saying is that it can be written in terms of well known constants. I guess we are just agreeing :-)

Comment: @Moron & @vonjd: You're both correct. As I said somewhere here previously, "closed-form" is just shorthand for "popular enough to be given a name and notation."

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, $ x = \pi/4 + D/2. $

Based on iteration $ \cos y = y $ there is a *fun method* to find D using a hand calculator:

Enter any real positive number and press Cos button some 10 or 15 times until none of last digits changes... this is the Dottie number.

Answer (score 0):

use $$\sin (2 x)\simeq \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{i e^{-\frac{i}{2}} (-1)^n x^{n/2} \left((2 i)^n \Gamma \left(n+1,-\frac{i}{2}\right)-e^i (-2 i)^n \Gamma \left(n+1,\frac{i}{2}\right)\right) I_n\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)}{2 \Gamma (n+1)}$$ few terms gives  good polynomial approximating root
or $$\sin (2 x)\simeq \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{i}{2}} (-1)^n \left(e^i E_{-n}\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)+E_{-n}\left(-\frac{i}{2}\right)\right) x^n \, _0\tilde{F}_1(;n+1;x)}{4 \Gamma (n+1)}$$