# What is the solution of $\cos(x)=x$?

Tags: trigonometry, closed-form, transcendental-equations

There is an unique solution with $x$ being approximately $0.739085$. But is there also a closed-form solution?

Comment: I wonder if it can be expressed in terms of the Lambert $W$-function, which some people would like to add to the list of closed forms.

Comment: The solution is unique since $y=x$ intersects $y= \cos x$ only one time.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: The other is a duplicate of this one. Check the dates.

Comment: @user88595, sorry about that.  I thought the proper procedure was to flag both; I should have just flagged the newer one.

Comment: I believe there is no known way to write this solution in terms of the Lambert W function.

Comment: Where there is a will there is usually a way.

Comment: It has a unique real solution.  Does it have a unique complex solution?

Comment: Would one like complex solutions to be added?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The equation in question is a [transcendental equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation). Apart of guessing, numerical or analytical methods, there is no way of solving the equation without using another transcendental function, and therefore argue in circles.

In this case, denote $g(x)=\cos x -x$, see that its derivative is negative with countable many zeros, and therefore $g$ is strictly decreasing, yielding that there is at most one solution to $g(x)=0$. Since $g(0)g(\pi/2)<0$ there is such a solution. Arbitrary precise approximations can be found using Newton, bisection, or false position method.

As user Myself commented, it is a challenge (not so hard) to prove that the sequence $x_{n+1}=\cos x_n, x_0 \in \Bbb{R}$ converges to the unique solution to $\cos x=x$.

Another related problem which I encountered last week when trying to help one of my friends for an exam is to find all continuous functions $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ with the property that $f(x)=f(\cos x)\ \forall x \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: But, in my understanding, being transcendental does not imply that the equation cannot have a closed form solution?

Comment: What do you mean with a closed form?

Comment: Some equations like $\sin x=x$ have solutions you can "put your hand on", in this case $x=0$. But this is just because we can guess them.

Comment: Something like "An equation is said to be a closed-form solution if it solves a given problem in terms of functions and mathematical operations from a given generally accepted set." [mathworld.wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Closed-FormSolution.html)

Comment: I have just seen [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9199/what-does-closed-form-solution-usually-mean) another discussion on what "closed form" means.

Comment: What's the point of arguing it is trancedential? Fixed point of the exponent is also transcedential, but can be expressed with an integral, for instance.

Comment: @Anixx Can you find the solution analytically? That is: write the solution without the aid of another equation or function.

Comment: Without another function? What do u mean? The answer by giorgiomugnaini gives an analytic solution.

Comment: An analytic solution can be approximated numerically. A closed form solution must contain a finite number of operations. A series or limit is not, in general, considered a closed form solution. See this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression  I gugess it depends on the definition you accept (or not). Still, it costs less to use a fixed point algorithm in order to find the solution of $\cos x=x$, than to use a series using Bessel functions.

Comment: How having closed-form expression is related to being transcedential?

Comment: If you search "transcendental equations" on the Internet, I guess things will become more clear (look at the Wikipedia link). The idea is that in a transcendental equation you cannot derive a formula for the solution $x$ using only basic arithmetic operations. You may express $x$ using arithmetic operations involving series, Lambert's function, or Bessel functions, but these functions are by definition solutions to some equations we cannot solve explicitly.

Comment: @BeniBogosel and algebra, and finite number of operations, afair, for OP's sake

Comment: I take it "solve for x" is also too hard in this case.

Comment: sin x=x is also transcendental but has an integer solution...

Comment: What is your proof that it cannot be solved "without using another transcendental function"? In any case, the wolfram article mentions that the solution is a transcendental number, maybe your standards of purity only allow the use of rational numbers? (pi is defined by sin x=0, just so you know). And btw, expressing the solution in terms of other transcendental functions needn't be arguing in circles, it can be a highly non-trivial statement.

Answer (score 24):

Mathworld calls this the [Dottie Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html). The page makes no mention of existence/non-existence of "closed" form and I would guess it is still open.

Answer (score 16):

Remembering the Kepler equation and its solution, the Dottie number can be analytically written as:

$$D = 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{J_{4n+1}(4n+1)}{4n+1} - \frac{J_{4n+3}(4n+3)}{4n+3}\right)$$

where $J_{n}$ are the Bessel functions.
Such series is convergent and can be evaluated numerically.

A proof and numerical evaluations are provided in :

[Solving $2x - \sin 2x = \pi/2$ for $0 < x < \pi/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10427/solving-2x-sin-2x-pi-2-for-0-x-pi-2)

Comment: more likely a link to Omega constant (fixed point of exponent) and an integral form.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227317/explaining-cos-infty/1175016#1175016

Answer (score 9):

Here is a closed form I just found. Using [Kepler’s Equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation), the [median of a beta distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), and [**Inverse Beta Regularized $\text I^{-1}_z(a,b)$**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseBetaRegularized.html). Here is the closed form:

$$\boxed{\text{Dottie Number}=\text D=\sin^{-1}\left(1-2\text I^{-1}_\frac12\left(\frac 12,\frac 32\right)\right)}$$

from [The Incomplete Beta function $\text B_z(a,b)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html):

$$\text B_{\sin^2(z)}\left(\frac 12,\frac32\right)=z+\cos(z)\sin(z)$$

taking the inverse, and a bit of algebra to get the form above. Also using the [Half Covered Sine](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hacoversine.html):

$$\text I^{-1}_\frac12\left(\frac 12,\frac 32\right)=\text{hacoversin}(\text {D)}=\frac12(1-\sin(\text D))\implies \text D= {\text{hacoversin}}^{-1} \text I^{-1}_\frac12\left(\frac 12,\frac 32\right) $$

With an [**error of $10^{-179}$ in this numerical evaluation**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sin%5E%28-1%29%281+-+2+inversebetaregularized%281%2F2%2C1%2F2%2C3%2F2%29%29-dottie+number). This is a side post since there already is an accepted answer. Please correct me and give me feedback!

> See explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4389528/intuition-for-why-the-dottie-number-is-an-inverse-sine-of-the-median-of-a-beta-d)

Comment: I check numerically is true with error of $10^{-100000}$.

Comment: See the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4389528/intuition-for-why-the-dottie-number-is-an-inverse-sine-of-the-median-of-a-beta-d) for more information

Comment: The factor 2 before the root is wrong (not needed) in your last comment. It should be $\sqrt{1-\left(2\text I^{-1}_\frac12\left(\frac 12,\frac 32\right)-1\right)^2}$

Comment: @Anixx Correct. I did not want to retype the mathjax, but you already did. Thanks.

Comment: Try to plot `Log[InverseBetaRegularized[1/2, x, 3/2]]` and `-1/x^0.889`, the graphics nearly coincide.

Comment: Would one like complex solutions to be added?

Answer (score 8):

As I know, there is no exact way to get the solution for $\cos(x)=x$. But, you can use Newton's Method to get an approximate answer:

> Consider the function $f(x)=\cos x−x$
>
> This gives us that $f'(x)=-\sin x-1$

Newton's Method states that $x_{\text{n+1}} = x_{\text{n}} - \dfrac{f(x_{\text{n}})}{f'(x_{\text{n}})}$

Then, just start at $x_{\text{0}}=1$ and repeat this method all over again, until you are satisfied. Don't forget that rounding numbers might lead to wrong answers!

Comment: Best answer as in easiest

Comment: So this is noncomputable, then.

Answer (score 4):

It is very easy to show that the equation $\cos x = x$ has a unique solution. For example take $f(x) = x - \cos x$ and notice that $f'(x) = 1+\sin x \ge 0$ (equality holding in isolated points) so $f(x)$ is strictly increasing and hence the equation can have at most one solution. Since $f(x)>0$ for $x\ge 1$ and $f(x)<0$ for $x\le 0$, and the function is continuous, by the intermediate values theorem there exists one and only one solution $\bar x \in [0,1]$.

For this particular equation there is also a very nice numeric approximation. In fact $\bar x = \lim x_n$ where $x_{n+1} = \cos (x_n)$ is any iteration of the function $\cos x$. You can easily find the numeric value for $\bar x$ simply putting any number in your pocket calculator and pressing repeatedly the $\cos$ button. In fact $\bar x$ is the fixed point of the $\cos$ function and, (at least in $[0,1]$) the $\cos$ function is a contraction hence every iterated sequence converges to the unique fixed point.

I can also convince you that $\bar x$ is an *exact* solution to the equation $\cos x = x$. I think that you agree that $\sqrt[3]2$ is an exact solution of the equation $x^3=2$, don't you? Now notice what's going on here... one notices that the function $x^3$ is strictly increasing hence invertible. You give a name to the inverse function and call it: cubic root. Then you find an algorithm to compute the cubic root on your calculator. Isn't this the same thing we did with the function $f(x) = x-\cos x$?

By *definition* the number $q = \sqrt[3]2$ is the only real number such that $q^3=2$. Analogously, the number $\bar x$ is the only number such that $\bar x-\cos \bar x=0$.

Answer (score 4):

Your equation cannot be solved in terms of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function), elementary functions and [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) or elementary functions and Generalized Lambert W of Mezö et al.. It can be solved in terms of "Leal-functions" and possibly by Generalized Lambert W of [Castle 2018].

**1.) Elementary functions, elementary numbers**

$$\cos(x)=x$$
$$\frac{1}{2}e^{ix}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-ix}=x$$
$$\frac{1}{2}e^{ix}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-ix}-x=0$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix})^2-xe^{ix}+\frac{1}{2}=0$$
$x\to\frac{t}{i}$:
$$\frac{1}{2}(e^t)^2+ite^t+\frac{1}{2}=0$$

The function on the left-hand side of the latter equation is an algebraic function in dependence of both $t$ and $e^t$. Liouville proved that such kind of functions (over a complex domain without isolated points) don't have [(partial) inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses) that are elementary functions.

The equation is also an algebraic equation in dependence of both $t$
and $e^t$. Lin proved, assuming [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) is true, that such kind of equations don't have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

[How can we show that $A(z,e^z)$ and $A(\ln (z),z)$ have no elementary inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586412/how-can-we-show-that-az-ez-and-a-ln-z-z-have-no-elementary-inverse)

**2.) Lambert W, Generalized Lambert W**

The latter equation also shows that the equation cannot be solved in terms of elementary functions and Lambert W or Generalized Lambert W of Mezö et. al. either. But possibly is it solvable in terms of Generalized Lambert W of [Castle 2018].

[Mezö 2017] Mezö, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mezö/Baricz 2017] Mezö, I.; Baricz, A.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

**3.) "Leal-functions"**

$$\cos(x)=x$$
$$\cos(x)-x=0$$
$x\to-t$:
$$t+\cos(t)=0$$
$$t=\text{Lcos}_2(0)$$
$$x=-\text{Lcos}_2(0)$$

[[Vazquez-Leal et al. 2020] Vazquez-Leal, H.; Sandoval-Hernandez, M. A.; Filobello-Ninoa, U.: The novel family of transcendental Leal-functions with applications to science and engineering. Heliyon 6 (2020) (11) e05418](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405844020322611)

Comment: @TymaGaidash For mathematics, it's enough to describe a new function. So we can work with the cited representations now. I wrote what I found so far. My aim was to make these inverses better known. That could help to find someone who implements it. At the moment, everyone has to make an own implementation for themselves.

Comment: @TymaGaidash You could help to try to find the relations between "Leal-functions" and InverseBetaRegularized function.

Answer (score 3):

I'm truth, there the above answers are correct, stating that the number currently has no closed form solution.

An old approximation that I came up with to $\cos$ can offer a decent approximation to the Dottie number however.

$$\sqrt[3.911]{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}
\approx \cos{x}$$

Setting the above approximation $=x$ and solving can give a closed form solution that lies within 4 decimal points of the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Not a closed form but a way to generate very good approximations of the Dottie number.

Since the solution is close to $\frac \pi 4$, we have for
$$y=x-\cos(x)$$ $$y=\frac{\pi -2 \sqrt{2}}{4} +\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)}{n!}\left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^n$$ Truncating to some order $O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^n\right)$ and using series reversion, we should get things like
$$x=\frac \pi 4+\frac{32 \left(11482+8119 \sqrt{2}\right) t}{\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)^{11}}-\frac{16
   \left(4756+3363 \sqrt{2}\right) t^2}{\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)^{11}}+\frac{32
   \left(5333+3771 \sqrt{2}\right) t^3}{3
   \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)^{11}}+O\left(t^4\right)$$ where $t=\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2}-2\right) \left(4 y+\pi -2 \sqrt{2}\right)$. Making $y=0$ and using this very truncated series would give
$$x \sim 0.739085133238$$ to be compared to the exact
$0.739085133215$

Playing with the $n$ of $O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^n\right)$, we could get the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_{(n)} \\
 1 &  \color{red}{0.739}536133515238 \\
 2 &  \color{red}{0.739}100520482138 \\
 3 &  \color{red}{0.739085}585917040 \\
 4 &  \color{red}{0.7390851}49503943 \\
 5 &  \color{red}{0.739085133}811963 \\
 6 &  \color{red}{0.7390851332}38222 \\
 7 &  \color{red}{0.73908513321}6073 \\
 8 &  \color{red}{0.7390851332151}98 \\
 9 &  \color{red}{0.73908513321516}2 \\
 10 & \color{red}{0.739085133215161}
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

*For the fun of it*, using the $\large 1,400$ years old approximation
$$\cos(x) \simeq\frac{\pi ^2-4x^2}{\pi ^2+x^2}\qquad \text{for} \qquad -\frac \pi 2 \leq x\leq\frac \pi 2$$ solving the cubic equation
$$x^3+4 x^2+\pi ^2 x-\pi ^2=0$$ gives as an *approximation*
$$x\sim -\frac{2}{3} \left(2+\sqrt{3 \pi ^2-16} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{128-63 \pi ^2}{2 \left(3 \pi
   ^2-16\right)^{3/2}}\right)\right)\right)=0.738305$$ that is to say a relative error of $0.1$%.

Comment: That's pretty impressive for a polynomial approximation! True, Newton's method $x'=(\cos x+x\sin x)/(1+\sin x)$ converges much faster, but your solution avoids the use of trig function calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cosine Taylor expansion and solve the polynomial 
$\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^i \frac{x^{2i}}{(2i)!}-x=0$
For example; for n=1,2 you get the approximations $x=1,x=\sqrt{3}-1$.

Comment: This method is impractical, as polynomial roots do not all have a closed-form solution. Therefore, other numerical approaches would be needed (e.g. Newton's method), which can equally well be done with the original formulation $\cos x-x$. So there is no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it IS already in closed form... if we follow the definition given here :https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression

since trigonometric functions are considered "well-known"... don't you agree?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You are right, $\cos(x)=x$ is an equation in closed form, it is an elementary equation. But the questioner asks for a closed-form solution (a solution in closed form) of that equation.

Answer (score 0):

My AskConstants "constant recognition" program at http://AskConstants.org proposed the explicit exact closed form

```
    RealInverseSphericalBesselY [0, -1, 1],
```

where $0$ is the order and $1$ is the branch number.

This was subsequently proved in my article at https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.00707

Comment: Sorry, you have not proved anything. Rayleigh's formulae (see [Wikipedia page on Bessel functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Bessel_functions)) explicitly give $j_n(x)$ and $y_n(x)$ as rational functions of $\sin x,\cos x,x$, including $y_0(x)=-\frac{\cos x}x$.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation with AskConstants.org when referring to it, otherwise the post may be considered spam.  See [What makes something spam and when should I flag it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035)

Comment: What is this function? It is definitely not a function in Mathematica.

Answer (score -2):

this can be really easy with the help of graphs. Draw the graphs of y= cosx and x=y. Intersection points on the graph will show the solutions.