# Algebraically find roots of a function composed of linear equations and trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, roots, transcendental-equations

I have the following equation of $t$:

$\text{C0}+(\text{C1}+\text{C2} t) \cos (\text{C4} t)+\sin (\text{C4} t) (\text{C7}+\text{C8} t)+\text{C5} \cos
   (\text{C6} t)+\text{C9} \sin (\text{C6} t)=0$

With $\text{C0}$ through $\text{C9}$ all real value constants. Solving for roots numerically is not a problem, what I am interested in is some expression enumerating the roots of $t$. I cant figure out where to start here, and my background is not enough to even know if this is possible. Thanks!

Comment: I do not think any such expression exists.  Usually an equation has to be very simple (in some sense) in order to have one.

Answer (score 1):

I cite [Beni Bogosel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7327/beni-bogosel) answering [such a question for much more simple equation $cos(x)=x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46934/what-is-the-solution-of-cosx-x): “The equation in question is a transcendental equation. Apart of guessing, numerical or analytical methods, there is no way of solving the equation without using another transcendental function, and therefore argue in circles”.  If you a interested in details than you can read the whole short discussion about the question.