# Convergence of cosine in the calculator

Tags: convergence-divergence, calculator

I noticed when playing with the calculator that if I repeatedly press "cos", starting with any number, it converges to $0.99984742$. Why does it happens??

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange!

Comment: This question has been asked more than once. See for example (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/46934)

Answer (score 1):

The equation $$\text{cos}(x)=x$$ can be solved via the iteration $x_{n+1}=\text{cos}(x_n)$ for any start value $x_0$ because after at most $2$ iterations, we have an absolute value less than $1$ and in the interval $[-1,1]$ , the derivate of $\cos(x)$, namely $-\text{sin}(x)$ has absolute value less than $1$.

You get the fixpoint of $\text{cos}(x)$ , which is the (unique) real solution of $\text{cos}(x)=x$.

You calculated in degrees and solved $x=\cos(x°)$. In radians, the equation would be $$cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)=x$$ , which has a unique solution as well. The convergence is very fast in this case because the derivate of $\text{cos}(\frac{\pi x}{180})$ is very small.

In radians, the solution is $0.73908513\cdots $

Comment: The iteration works under some conditions shown in the Banach-fixpoint-theorem.

Comment: You forgot a $7$, the solution is $$0.9998477415\cdots $$

Answer (score 0):

If you had used the iterated solution to  obtain  this way  $ \cos x = x $ in radians you get:

$$ x= 0.73908513 $$

Your calculator setting in degrees produces this solution:

$$ x= 0.9998474...$$

This is a way to evaluate fixed points convergence. A sketch would be helpful to see how the small squares shrink to the fixed point in x-y plot.

Comment: A $7$ is missing, see my comment above.

Comment: No, it is degrees set in hand calculator.

Comment: The result cotains two consecutive sevens, this is what I mean.

Comment: OK., it is true