# What number does the recurrence $x_{n+1} = \cos(x_n) $ converge to?

Tags: recurrence-relations

The recurrence $x_{n+1} = \cos(x_n) $ seems to converge to a value around .739 no matter what number is chosen for $x_0$, even complex numbers. What is the exact number that this recurrence converges to?

Comment: If the limit exists, then $L=\cos(L)$. You can't solve this analytically.https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3Dcos(x)

Comment: Is there a proof that $L=cos(L)$ can't be solved analytically?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46934/what-is-the-solution-of-cosx-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the limit exists, then $L=\cos(L)$. The solution to this equation is the [Dottie number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- $f: x\mapsto \cos(\cos x)$ is increasing on $[0,1]$.
- For all $n\ge 1$, $x_n \in [0,1]$
- Let $a_n = x_{2n}$ and $b_n = x_{2n+1}$. Use $f$ to prove that $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ both converge to the same value. Conclude that $(x_n)$ converges (the value to which it converges is the unique fixed point of $\cos$).