# Find the values of x: $- 2 (1 - \cos x) = \frac x2$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to find $x$?

The issue I have here is that $x$ is there even on the RHS.

If you could help it would be really nice as I have a test tomorrow.

Comment: is this$$ -2(1-\cos(x))=\frac{x}{2}$$?

Comment: What efforts did you make to solve this?

Comment: One obvious solution is $x=0$, but I'm not sure if it is possible to find the exact value of the other two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the equation as $1+\frac x 4= cosx$ and draw the graph $y=1+\frac x 4$ and $y= cosx$, on the same figure you get three point of intersection. The values of $x$ are at the point of intersection of these two curve where one is zero and another two you have to find numerically or a given range.

Comment: THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! SO MUCH!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Answering this as an answer since I don't have enough reputation to comment:

[What is the solution of cos(x)=x?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46934/what-is-the-solution-of-cosx-x) is similar to this question, and as the majority of answers point out, there is no solution in terms of standard functions, however you can prove it has solutions using IVT.