# Solution of $\cos^{-1}x=\cos x=x$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

From the graph I observed that these 3 functions cut at a particular point.

[image]

but what should be the value of x which will satisfy the given eqn I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: Welcome Aniruth. $y=arc \cos x=\cos x$ so $\cos y=x$ which symmetric with $\cos x =y$, that is $x=y$, no need for third equation i,e, $y=x$

Comment: @Anirudh Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\cos^{-1}x$ is the inverse of $\cos x$ their intersection must be at the point such that

$$\cos x=x$$

which is a trascendental equation discussed here [What is the solution of cos(x)=x?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/46934/505767).

Answer (score 0):

You want to solve $f(x)=0$ with $f(x):=x-\cos x$. This can only be done numerically. Since $g(x):=x-\frac{f}{f'}=\frac{x\sin x+\cos x}{1+\sin x}$, we can approximate the root with the Newton-Raphson method. The root looks close to $1$ to me, so define $x_0:=1,\,x_{n+1}:=g(x_n)$. The sequence $x_n$ continues 0.75036386784, 0.739112890911, 0.739085133385, 0.739085133215, 0.739085133215. That gets us the result to as many decimal places as Python gave me.