# Finding the intersection of $\cos(x)$ and $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to find the intersection of two functions. One is $f(x) = cos(x)$. The other one is $g(x) = x$. When I do the normal steps like equating both functions and finding the roots, I get something like this
$\cos(x) = x$
$\cos(x) - x = 0$
How do I proceed further? Is there any argument to cosine such that it would give back the same argument as output? If yes, how do I find it analytically without graphing the function?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46934/what-is-the-solution-of-cosx-x

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dottie_Number

Comment: You can try fixed-point iteration or Newton's Method get an approximate answer