# Find angle subtended by overlapping circles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Solving $2x - \sin 2x = \pi/2$ for $0 &lt; x &lt; \pi/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10427/solving-2x-sin-2x-pi-2-for-0-x-pi-2)

I need a little nudge for this problem. I have figured out everything but the last bit(albeit the most important!).

> Two equal circles of radii $a$ intersect and the common chord subtends an angle of $2\theta$ radians at either center. Find an expression for the area of the region common to the two circles.
>
> If this area is equal to half the area of either circle, estimate the value of $\theta$ which satisfies this equation

Using the sector area formula, I found the area of the minor segment = $\dfrac{1}{2}a^2(2\theta - \sin 2\theta)$

Hence area of overlapping region = $a^2(2\theta - \sin 2\theta)$

Since this area is half of either circle, $a^2(2\theta - \sin 2\theta) = \dfrac{1}{2}\pi a^2$

Simplifying further, I got,

$\sin 2\theta = 2\theta - \dfrac{\pi}{2}$

This is how far I have gotten. I don't know how to solve this equation. Can you guys help? Thanks again.

Comment: Hint: Let $\phi = 2\theta - \pi/2$, and express the equation in terms of $\phi$, after simplifying $\sin (\phi + \pi/2)$. You still get an equation that you can't solve, but you can draw a graph to estimate the solution. (Or use the first two terms of the Taylor expansion.)

Comment: Nice substitution, makes for an easier graph. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the point of the question is that you are asked to estimate the value.  I suggest that you plot the two curves $\sin 2\theta$ and $2\theta - \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and estimate where they intersect.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing just that. $\theta \approx 1.2$ radians

Answer (score 1):

Well your work so far implies:

$\theta = \dfrac{\sin 2\theta}{2}+ \dfrac{\pi}{4}$

And you know that $\sin 2\theta$ is bounded.

You are asked to estimate ... so could you use an iterative method, or a graphical method, or (likely messier) expand the series for $\sin 2\theta$ ...

Comment: So, continuing the thought a little, you can see that $\sin 2\theta$ is positive, for the range of possibilities for $\theta$ given by the bound.

Comment: I did the graphical solution. The iterative method opened up some new ideas I need to learn, Thanks.