# Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\underset{n}{\underbrace{\cos(\cos(...\cos x))}}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, dynamical-systems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explaining $\cos^\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227317/explaining-cos-infty)

Does the following limit exist?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\underset{n}{\underbrace{\cos(\cos(...\cos x))}}$$

If yes, find the limit.

If no, please explain why the limit doesn't exist.

I think, the limit exists.

So, I tried to use Squeeze theorem but didn't work.

Comment: You should guess what the limit should be, then prove that it actually is the limit.

Comment: yes, I also try to use a sequence instead the limit. $a_1=\cos x$ and $a_{n+1}=\cos(a_n)$ , but my friend said that was wrong

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227317/explaining-cos-infty/227320).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may treat is as dynamical system with state transition function $f(x) = cos(x)$. After first two iterations $f^{n > 2}(x)$ will lay in interval $I = [cos(1), 1]$. Line $g(x) = x$ will intercept $cos(x)$ in interval $I$ exactly once so $cos(x)$ has unique fixed point in $I$. Because of unique fixed point and because $|f'(x)| < 1$ sequence $f^n(x)$ will converge to this fixed point.

Comment: Consider adding this answer to the earlier duplicate, linked above.  Rather than calling it a "dynamical system", though, it would be a little more self- contained to call it a fixed-point iteration.

Comment: I have copied this answer to duplicate post.