# Area of region bounded by graphs $y=\cos x$ , $y= x$ and $y$-axis.

Tags: integration

I am currently stuck on this integration question in Calculus.

What is the area of the region in the first quadrant enclosed by the graphs of
$y = \cos x$ , $y = x$ and the $y$-axis?

I had drawn out the graph and I have no idea how to find the point of intersection. I am stuck at finding the boundary when $x=\cos x$. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=cosx-x$ is a transcendental equation so there are no exact solution but you can get approximation. Check this out [Solving $\cos x=x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557975/solving-cos-x-x?noredirect=1&lq=1). You can use the approximation to get the approximate answer as $\int_0^{0.7391} (\cos x-x)dx$

Comment: It is more accurate $\;0.7391\;$ ...