# Prove that $\cos x=bx$ has a single solution in the closed interval $ [0, \pi /2]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Prove that the equation $\cos x = bx$ has a single solution in the closed interval $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ if $b \ge 0$.

1) If $b = 0$

In such case $\cos x=0 \cdot x$ and only one $x$ can satisfy such equation in the given interval which is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

2) If $b > 0$

Let $E(x) = \cos x - bx$

$E(0) > 0$

$E(\frac{\pi}{2}) < 0$

$E(x)$ is continuous for all $x$ as it is the difference of a polynomial and $\cos$. Thus according to intermediate value theorem there must be an $x_1$ in the interval $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ such that $E(x_1) = 0$. Suppose that there's another $x= x_2 \neq x_1$ such that $E(x_2) = 0$. $E(x)$ is continuous in $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ and differentiable in $(0,  \frac{\pi}{2})$ thus according to Rolle theorem there must a root to $E'(x)$.

$E'(x) = -\sin x - b$

If we try to find the root of $E'(x)$:

$-\sin x-b = 0$

$-\sin x = b$

But $\sin x>0$ in the interval $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $b>0$ hence it's a contradiction. Thus there's not a second root for $E(x)$ in the open interval.

Now we just need to check if $x = 0$ or  $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ will result in a zero.

$\cos\frac{\pi}{2}=b\frac{\pi}{2}$

$0 = b\frac{\pi}{2} \Rightarrow$ contradiction as $b > 0$

$\cos 0 = b\cdot0$

$1 \neq 0 \Rightarrow$ contradiction.

Not sure if I actually had to do the last part of check the values on the edges of the closed interval, I think I have to because Intermidiate value and Rolle theorems talk about having results in the open interval.

Please let me know if my solution is correct.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Banach Fixed Point theorem?

Comment: No and this means I can't use it in class.

Comment: Your solution is correct and is written rather well. :)

Comment: I completely agree with @Clayton. The proof looks good!

Comment: see (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/557975)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is perfectly fine. One thing that could make the proof faster is noticing that $E'(x) < 0$ on $[0,\frac\pi 2]$, thus $E$ is strictly decreasing and therefore injective, so there is at most one $x$ such that $E(x) = 0$.

Comment: I would still have to do Intermediate theorem though right?

Comment: To show the existence, yes. Injectivity just addresses uniqueness.