# If $a_{n+1}=\cos(a_n)$ for $n\ge0$ and $a_0 \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, find $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$ if it exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $a_{n+1}=\cos(a_n)$ for $n\ge0$ and $a_0 \in [0,\pi/2]$

Find $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$ if it exists.

I drew some sketches and it does seem like the limit exists, it's probably $x$ such that $\cos(x)=x$

I have no idea how to go about solving this, hints would really be appreciated.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think that is all you need to say: it's $x$ such that $\cos(x) = x$. I don't believe there's an expression of this $x$ in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Try induction to prove that $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$ is monotone.

Comment: Oh, I just realize you need to show the limit exists too.

Comment: [Here's](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227317/explaining-cos-infty) a related post.

Comment: If you want to find the limit you can use Newton's method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f=\cos$. Note that $a_1$ is in $I=[0,1]$ and that $f(I)\subset I$. Furthermore, for every $x$ in $I$, $-c\lt f'(x)\leqslant0$ with $c\lt1$ hence $(a_{2n})_{n\geqslant1}$ and $(a_{2n-1})_{n\geqslant1}$ are monotonous sequences with values in $I$ and they both converge to the unique solution $\ell$ of $\cos\ell=\ell$ in $[0,1]$.

(Numerically, $c=\sin(1)\lt.85$, $|a_{n+1}-\ell|\leqslant c\cdot|a_n-\ell|$ for every $n\geqslant1$, which implies that $|a_n-\ell|\leqslant c^{n-1}$ for every $n\geqslant1$, and $\ell\approx0.739085$.)

Answer (score 0):

The "Fixed Point" method in numerical analysis says that if a function is continuously differentiable in a neighbourhood of a fixed point $x_0$ and 
$$
|f'(x)| \lt 1
$$
it will converge to a fixed point

source: [Fixed point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_%28mathematics%29)

Comment: In this case one has only $\mid f'(x)\mid\leq1$.

Comment: But in a neighbourhood of the answer, $|f'(x)|<1$.