# Is there an analytic solution to find zeroes of a polynomial plus sin()?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, roots

Is there an analytic solution to find the zeroes of an equation of the form:
$$0 = at^2+bt+c+\sin(mt^2+nt+o)$$

Comment: No. $\qquad \qquad$

Comment: By "analytic solution" you are allowing infinite series, Bessel functions, etc? There may be such an expression for the roots, but it sure won't be pretty...

Comment: @ZacharySelk I wouldn't be so confident: consider that $\cos x -x = 0$ has an analytic solution, for instance: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10427/solving-2x-sin-2x-pi-2-for-0-x-pi-2